# Django admin field class override for validation

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to implement phone value validation in Django admin. For this I want to use already existing Field class localflavor.lt.forms.LTPhoneField. But with the simplified code example bellow validation does not work:

```
# from model.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

# from admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from localflavor.lt.forms import LTPhoneField

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    phone = LTPhoneField()
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

**Edit:** Solved. See my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding additional forms.ModelForm class like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm)
    phone = LTPhoneField()

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like :

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    phone = LTPhoneField()
    def clean_phone(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["phone"]
admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

****Not Tested**

Comment: What should be in this "# do something" area? LTPhoneField has clean() method that does validation: [souce code](https://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/localflavor/lt/forms/#LTPhoneField)